# "== 0" Not Working After Select From mysql

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, select, zero

I want my code to check if the available copies for a specific book is 0 so that it will update its status to 1(making it unavailable)

Now my problem is that whenever this part of my code runs, the IF statement is always true regardless if the Select statement before it returns a value of 1 or higher. So now, the book becomes unavailable even if it still has copies

```
$sql = "SELECT Available_Copies from books WHERE id = '$bid'";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
if($sql == 0)
{   
  $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE books SET status = 1 WHERE id = '$bid' ");
  $query = $conn->query($sql);              
}
```

Comment: Because `query` function returns not what you expect.

Comment: `$sql` is just a string which you're comparing with the number `0`. Don't you mean to compare the value of of the column `Available_Copies`? Right now, you're not using the results of the first query at all.

Comment: SQL injections and race conditions are possible within this code.. You should use prepared statements to solve the SQL injection.. And you should merge the two queries as one with `UPDATE ... INNER JOIN ... SET ...`  syntax to solve the race condition or use a co-related `UPDATE` subquery to keep database protablitiy.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Dharman really hackers will not corrupt your data, they are after your passwords and other information, if they delete a table if is directly clear something **bad** has happend.. the table delete if it would work for PHP MySQL clients is more a thing for scriptkiddies

Comment: @RaymondNijland Why would you think I am talking about hackers?

Comment: @RaymondNijland - There are a lot of script kiddies and trolls out there that would love to corrupt databases if they got the opportunity. It's not only evil black hat hackers that tries to steal your data you need to worry about. SQL-injections doesn't always need to be on purpose either.

Comment: I know people named `O'Connor` who would love to use internet without corrupting other people's databases. Please help them...

Comment: thats also not the point besides `1; DROP TABLE table` kind of injections will not work in PHP @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @RaymondNijland True but you can still use [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: if you use mysqli_multi_query @Dharman then you are asking about it.

Comment: *"You're the one missing the point, friend"* @LightnessRacesinOrbit no iám not missing the point notice i was the first that mentioned in the comments about the SQL injection leaks and race condition in his code, friend.

Comment: @RaymondNijland There is never any reason to defend SQL concatenation with the data. They should always be separate!

Comment: *" There is never any reason to defend SQL concatenation with the data. They should always be separate! "* @Dharman where did i say that, have you noticed i was the first that mentioned the leaks in this code?

Comment: @RaymondNijland - I think you're taking the bobby-tables comic a bit too literal. It's just an illustration about SQL injections in general. Anyway.. this is _way_ off-topic.

Comment: @Raymond The point is to _always_ follow the advice that you indeed even gave yourself, not to cherry-pick when you think it is and isn't necessary. That way, when you're wrong about when it is and isn't necessary, it doesn't matter. #foolproof #failsafe

Comment: **to make one thing clear i never said not using prepared statements was not necessary here**, i only said that `1; DROP TABLE table` kind off injections are more or less impossible in PHP MySQL Clients if you are using the correct functions

Comment: @RaymondNijland Well, that's true; I only read half of the conversation before ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two queries can be joined into one:

```
$sql = "UPDATE books SET status = 1 WHERE id = '$bid' AND Available_Copies = 0";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: Could you please don't concatenate SQL in your answer, or at least put in bold that this should be avoided!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you're examining the variable `$sql`, which is just a PHP non-empty string. Comparing that to `0` will never work.

But, assuming you instead meant this:

```
   $sql = "SELECT Available_Copies from books WHERE id = '$bid'";
   $query = $conn->query($sql);
   if($query == 0)
//    ^^^^^^
```

… then that's not right either. [`query()` returns a *result object*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). It does not return the value of a column retrieved by your query. In general, your PHP code does not know about your SQL code; these are separate domains. The result object is the magic glue that bridges the two domains together, but you have to use it as documented in order to get the results you expect.

See the manual for [how to use the result object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php). `fetch_row()` looks good for you.

Also, I would recommend calling it `$result`, not `$query`, because it's a result, not a query.

**However!** You should consider merging your operations into one, because currently the `SELECT` is completely unnecessary:

```
UPDATE books SET status = 1 WHERE id = '$bid' AND Available_Copies = 0
```

This avoids race conditions and excess overhead, and the need to check the column value in PHP *at all*!

Also, [parameterise your SQL statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to [safeguard your system from accidents and terrorists](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Don't do it the way I've shown above. Don't interpolate `$bid` into the string like that. If your learning material (book) does not say this, get different learning material.

Comment: In this case an INNER JOIN is not needed to merge the two queries, since it’s all the same table. The UPDATE query just also needs `AND Available_Copies = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here `$sql`  will only contain your query string. 
So for getting the value you should use

```
$query->fetch_assoc()
```

So your actual code will be

```
$sql = "SELECT Available_Copies from books WHERE id = '$bid'";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
if($result['Available_Copies'] == 0)
{  
  $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE books SET status = 1 WHERE id = '$bid' ");
  $query = $conn->query($sql);              
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Corrected my answer

Comment: There’s no reason to do this as two queries; it’s inefficient and subject to race conditions. Though this answer does point out how to properly determine the value from the query, which OP struggled with.